# Does the Upper and Lower Derivative Definition Imply the Standard Derivative Definition?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The upper and lower derivatives of a function f on the interior of a set $E$ are defined as follows: for $x\in E\strut^\mathrm{o}$, $$\overline Df(x)= \lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left[\sup_{0<|t|\leq h} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} \right];$$ $$\underline Df(x)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left[\inf_{0<|t|\leq h} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} \right].$$ The function $f$ is differentiable in $x$ $\iff$ $\overline Df(x)=\underline Df(x)$.

My question is that, does the definition above of differentiability imply the 'standard' definition of differentiability? That is, if $\overline Df(x)=\underline Df(x)$, does it imply that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}?$$

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are following Royden & Fitzpatrick's *Real Analysis*. The definition you are citing also requires the upper and lower derivatives to be finite.

The limit of a sequence exists iff its limit superior and inferior are equal. Further we can convert the above expressions to discrete ones:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L \iff [\forall \{x_n\}_n: x_n\to x_0 \implies f(x_n)\to L],$$

hence indeed the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: I am not understanding your answer, could you please provide us with more details?

Comment: Using the discretization one can realize that the expressions for upper and lower derivatives are equal to appropriate $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$, from which the relation with regular limits is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

The $\limsup$ has the following property:

> Let $\limsup_{x \to p}f(x)=A$. Then, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ such that $f(x)<A+\epsilon$ for all $x \in U$.

An analogous result holds for $\liminf$. By combining both of these (and the fact that if the limit exists, then $\limsup=\liminf$), you should be able to prove that the definitions of differentiability are equivalent.

The property mentioned above is used to prove that if $\limsup=\liminf$, then $\lim$ exists.